# why its difficult to set point padding and placement dynamically according to the data in fixed column chart (highcharts)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, highcharts

So, i am new to highcharts and i got stuck in a situation. I came across two charts in Highcharts. The chart in the below link

```
'http://jsfiddle.net/v5618cwk/'
```

Here the point interval is dynamically added with the formula '24 * 3600 * 1000', so when the data increases, it dynamically creates the point interval. Then i came across fixed column chart.

'http://jsfiddle.net/cf9xe3f0/'

I tried very much but i can't create the padding and placement dynamically when data increases.

I don't know why its difficult, its a challenging task.

Help me with this case guys. Thanks

Comment: These charts have two very different xAxis types. The first is a time based axis while the second is a categorical. What exactly are you trying to do? When does the "data increase"? Are you adding a new point or changing existing data point values?

Comment: Actually, in fixed column chart, i should add the padding and placement dynamically according to the data.So, when data increase like 10 data series to 20 data series, the padding and placement should add dynamically. So, u have any idea how to add it dynamically or have any formula to add it. Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you adding a new location to the xAxis categories ('Seattle HQ', 'San Francisco', 'Tokyo') or a new data series ('Employees', 'Profit', etc)?

Comment: i am adding new data series, so i cant change the padding and placement statically when adding the data. So, you have any idea or formula to add it dynamically?

Comment: yes....even i have the same doubt. Can someone give a solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not know what your new series is going to be like here is a general method. You need to add your series and change the `pointPlacement`. To do this first change your `pointPlacement` to some appropriate value and add your new series. I did this on a button click but the general idea holds for any method:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
        if (chart.series[i].options.yAxis === 0) {
            chart.series[i].update({
                //pointPadding: 0.4,
                pointPlacement: -0.4
            });
        } else {
            chart.series[i].update({
                //pointPadding: 0.4,
                pointPlacement: 0.4
            });
        }
    }

    chart.addSeries({
        name: 'A New Series',
        color: 'green',
        data: [300, 150, 350],
        tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$',
            valueSuffix: ' M'
        },
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: 0.1,
        yAxis: 1
    });
});
```

The key things to understand are [`series.update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) and [`chart.addSeries()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries). You can add the series and then do a global update all as well. Depending on how many new series you have you may reach an upper limit where it just doesn't look good no matter what you do.

Live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/7htqgkaa/).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by overlapped. The new series (green bar) is not overlapped and the other series get moved out of the way. It is up to you to determine what the correct position of the new series should be and what the new positions of the old series should become. I just gave you a method to achieve that with the `update()` logic.